# Can you send an electrical signal to open/close a switch via iphone jack?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to know how to make an app to be able to make a circuit close using iphone's audio jack. An example of this this is Happy Trigger http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1435018402/trigger-happy-camera-remote

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to play some sound and then detect the sound in your apparatus somehow.  Probably best to use a particular frequency or combination of frequencies, vs "any sound".

Comment: Is your problem on software (code) or hardware side? You can easily send let's say 4kHz to open and 8kHz to close. On hardware side, as Hot Licks said, you'll need to detect this frequencies either with narrow-band-pass filters either with some microcontroller. But that would be the question for http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I believe what they do is simply play some arbitrary audio and use the resulting signal.

Comment: I'm sure that they use the voltage created by playing a sound over the headphone jack to close a transistor which fires the camera.